# confused with int Assignments in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to work on the ArmStrong number,
So here is my code

```
public class NewArmStrongNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 153,armNum=0;
    while(num>0){
        int temp = num%10;
        armNum = armNum+(temp*temp*temp);

        num = num/10;

    }
    System.out.println(num==armNum);

}
```

}

The result i am getting is false,May i know why?

Comment: You would be able to tell faster if you ran the code in a debugger, set a breakpoint, and stepped through to see how your assumptions aren't correct.

Comment: At the end, num = 0. Try storing value of `num` into some `temp2` variable using `temp2 = num` before the loop, and at last do `System.out.println(temp2==armNum);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

num is decreasing as it is /10 each time, and the loop exits when num is 0.

armNum is potentially increasing each time it goes through the loop.

So unless armNum is 0, it will be false.

Answer (score 0):

You must save the `num`in some other variable to compare it with `armNum`. It is because `num` will always be **0** at the end of the `while` loop. so `(num==armNum)` will always be `false`

Answer (score 0):

Mine works, according to the definition of [Armstrong numbers](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html):

```
package math.numbers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 7/28/2017.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378317/confused-with-int-assignments-in-java
 * @link http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html
 */
public class Armstrong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> armstrong = IntStream.range(0, 1000000).filter(Armstrong::isArmstrong).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(armstrong);
    }

    public static boolean isArmstrong(int n) {
        boolean armstrong = false;
        int sum = 0;
        int temp = n;
        while (temp > 0) {
            int x = temp % 10;
            sum += x * x * x;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        armstrong = (sum == n);
        return armstrong;
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get:

```
[0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407]
```